# No permissions to change tty mode inside a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, tty, ioctl

I'm trying to run some software inside a docker container, which wants to do VT_SETMODE for the tty currently in use. This will always fail with an error saying "Operation not permitted".

I've tried playing around with permissions/groups with no luck.

Finally I created a small snippet to reproduce the error:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/vt.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
        const char *tty_path;
        tty_path = "/dev/tty1";

        int fd = open(tty_path, O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);

        if (fd < 0) {
                printf("ERROR: Failed to open %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }

        struct vt_mode mode = {
                .mode = VT_AUTO,
        };
        errno = 0;

        ioctl(fd, VT_SETMODE, &mode);

        if (errno) {
                printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I ran the code inside a docker container with a simple dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux/base

RUN pacman -Sy --noconfirm gcc
```

That was started with command:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t tty-test . && docker run --device /dev/tty1 -v $HOME/tty-test:/volume -it tty-test /bin/bash -c 'cd /volume && gcc tty_r.c && ./a.out ; /bin/bash'
```

Output is this:

```
ERROR: Operation not permitted
```

Can anyone explain why the tty is not accessible from the container, or is there some way to give more control to the container?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems that I have solved my own problem. I was trying to run the code inside a container which had no privilege to do tty-configuration. Adding `--cap-add SYS_TTY_CONFIG` to the docker run command fixed the issue.